# Contract keeping track of token transfers

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20

I want to create a contract that keeps track of what tokens have been sent to it (what amount, type, who sent it, etc.) I can do this for ERC721, ERC 777, ERC 1155 using the "tokenReceived" callback after tokens are transferred. Is there a way to do this for ER20s?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible since the ERC-20 standard doesn't have such functionality.

It should be possible to have an off-chain part that tracks `Transfer` events and the forwards a message to the contract.

Another thing you should consider is that there are tokens like AMP whose balances change without emitting events.